# Reads on an entity group sparking contention?

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, datastore

I have a function in my app that does some processing in a transaction - creates or fails to create an entity depending on the attributes of others in the entity group.

I have been doing some testing that sees this function called in fast succession, a few times a second is possible in these tests.

The function triggers some deferred tasks that read from the entity group, but do not write to it.

I noticed something funny - when these tasks are triggered immediately, and interleave with the main function calls, I get contention errors quite frequently.

If I put a countdown of a couple of seconds on the deferred tasks, the main functions process successfully.

That suggests to me that the deferred tasks are causing contention on the entity group the main function writes to - but I thought reads from an entity group couldn't do this? Do look ups by keyname cause contention? Queries with filters?

It's kind of puzzling me. Should this be happening? I've read elsewhere that there is a limit of 1 write per second per entity group, but my tests routinely break that limit...at least when my spin-off deferred tasks are delayed for a couple of seconds.

This is on production, by the way.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I should note also, since it may be relevant, that the deferred tasks are themselves transactions...can reads on an entity group in a transaction cause contention on that group?